# How to find all possible solutions in backtracking

Tags: c, backtracking

I'm trying to implement a backtracking algorithm (it's supposed to run through a given amount of people and check all possible pairs, each pair has a certain score and the goal is to find how many times the "maximum" score appears; so I need to check all possible solutions).

The problem is I can't understand how to make my function actually 'backtrack'... when it finds a solution, it goes all the way back to the root. How do I go back to a point where I can try a different path, and make it go that path rather than doing the same one again?

Here is my code, though I know my idea is probably wrong... it's just that I tried to think about it in so many ways and I'm absolutely lost here.
Thanks for any help!

```
void allPairs (int x, int pref[], bool teamed[], int* max, int score, int numWorkers) {
    for (int i=1; i < numWorkers; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        pairTwo(x, i, pref, teamed, max, score, numWorkers, &count);
    }
}

int pairTwo (int x, int y, int pref[], bool teamed[], int* max, int score, int numWorkers, int* howMany) {
        if (x >= numWorkers) {
            arrToZero(teamed, numWorkers);
            return score;
        }
        else if (x==y) {
            if(y < numWorkers-1) {
                y = findUnteamed(teamed, y+1, numWorkers);
            }
            else {
                arrToZero(teamed, numWorkers);
                return score;
            }
        }

        int pairScore = sumPair(pref, x, y, teamed, numWorkers);
        x = findUnteamed(teamed, x, numWorkers);
        y = findUnteamed(teamed, 0, numWorkers);
        int temp = pairTwo(x, y, pref, teamed, max, score + pairScore, numWorkers, howMany);
        teamed[x] = 0; // here I tried to "erase" the last move but it's useless
        teamed[y] = 0;
        if (temp >= *max) {
            max = &temp;
            *howMany++;
            printf("There are %d optimal pairings:, with a total score of: %d\n", *howMany, *max);
            return *max;
        }
        else {
        return -1;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your recursive call to `pairTwo` have to be in a loop to examine all possibilities, `x` and `y` must iterate over all *unteamed*, not just the first found.

Answer (score 1):

Backtracking is confusing if you do not adhere to the exact algorithm it follows. Unofficial names for methods in a backtracking algorithm are widely accepted, and help debug the code much easier.

Standard recursive backtracking algorithm consists of solve(), getSuccessors(), isGoal(), and isValid(). Using an example of an array of ints that is being manuipulated to be solved, the solve() function look like this:

```
int[] solve(int[] list) {
    if ( isGoal( list ) ) {
        return list;
    }
    int[][] successors = getSuccessors( list )
    for (int[] successor : successors) {
        if ( isValid( successor ) ) {
            if ( sizeof( solve( successor ) ) != 0 ) {
                return successor;
            }
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

Where `getSuccessors()` returns a list of *deep copies* of the current array that have been modified to explore the new solutions, `isGoal()` checks if the solution has been found, and `isValid()` checks if it is possible to find the goal continuing down this current path. These three functions are specific to the problem you are trying to solve.

Alternatively, an iterative version of solve() exists where the initial state is placed into an empty stack, though you'd need a stack constructed in the first place. Check the Wikipedia page on iterative backtracking to see how that solve method works.